# Java - How to regex this string?

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my input String:

```
String content = "Hello [To:admin1] Admin 1 , Good Morning [To:user2] 
                 Admin 1, GoodNight [To:user1] Admin 1";
```

I want to convert this to:

```
"Hello [To] Admin 1 , Good Morning [To] Admin 1, GoodNight [To] Admin 1"
```

I am trying to use Regular Expressions but I not able to.

I want replace the text `[To:xxxx]` with `[To]`

Please suggest what can be done.

Comment: `\[To:.*\]` should match, `\[To\]` should replace

Comment: @mcalex it wont work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this :

```
String st = "Hello [To:admin1] Admin 1 , Good Morning [To:user2] Admin 1, GoodNight [To:user1] Admin 1";
st = st.replaceAll("\\[To:.*?\\]", "[To]");
System.out.println(st);
```

This will replace every thing between `[To:` and `]` to `[To]`, and this will show you :

```
Hello [To] Admin 1 , Good Morning [To] Admin 1, GoodNight [To] Admin 1
```

Comment: Tks you so much...word for me..

Comment: you are welcome @cheng :)

Comment: Sorry, i has check again....I think can mutiple accept mark :P...answer of Hardy Feng also great

Answer (score 2):

Just alternative solution by java regex.

```
    String st = "Hello [To:admin1] Admin 1 , Good Morning [To:user2] Admin 1, GoodNight [To:user1] Admin 1";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[To:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\]");
    String result = pattern.matcher(st).replaceAll("[To]");
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Yes, it work for me too....tks Hardy Feng :D

Answer (score 1):

```
String stringToSearch = "Hello [To:admin1] Admin 1 , Good Morning [To:user2] Admin 1, GoodNight [To:user1] Admin 1";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("To:[\\w]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb,"To");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```